# Android - Confused about Firestore AuthStateListener()

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In my app I have a mainactivity that implements authstatelistener, and redirects the user to a login screen if the state is changed (user signs out or timed out). In the app I have a total of about 6 other activities, which contain an navhostfragment container of many fragments.

The purpose of the activities to is to collect user data and send it to firebase.

I am confused if I need to implement authstatelistener in all these activities as well. If I do not do this, will the UI not respond to the user being signed out (and will this happen if the main activity remains in the history stack?).

I read a few questions on this and have found very different answers for different use cases. Currently I am not doing this, and my app runs just fine, but I have no clue if this will cause a bug in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the auth state listener on the level of activities, then indeed you'll need to implement it in each activity. You'll typically want to implement it in a base-class in that case, and derive all your concrete activities from that.

Comment: thanks, in my case I added the authstatelistener with a sign out method, as well as onstart and onstop in every activity. Is this needed? Or should I just be doing a null check or adding more code?